# How can I fix my redux reducer and action creator in react?

Tags: javascript, redux, reducers

I wrote an `onChange` function with redux but its not working.

My action creator is working well but my reducer is not working.

I have the `console.log(1)` but `console.log(2)` is not working.

```
export const changeScore = (team, value) => {
  console.log(1);
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.CHANGE_SCORE,
    payload: { team, value },
  };
};

case (ActionTypes.CHANGE_SCORE):
  console.log(2);
  return {
    ...state,
    data: state.data.map((item) => (
      item.id === action.payload.team.id
        ? { ...item, score: action.payload.value }
        : item
    )),
  };
```

Comment: are you dispatching the changeScore method properly?

Comment: add some more code to understand the issue properly